# Uploading files/images to database with CakePHP3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How do you upload images/files to database with CakePHP3? I'm creating a profile page which users can upload their profile images. The database is consisted of Images table (id, filename and image(BLOB)), and Users table, which have image_id column to associate with Images. The following is my code.

Part of Templete file

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user, ['type' => 'file']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('image', ['type' => 'file']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Save')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Controller file

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, ['contain' => ['Images']]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $data = $this->request->data;
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $data);
        if ($data['image']['size'] > 0 && $data['image']['error'] == 0) {
        // Image is uploaded.
            if (!empty($user->image_id)) {
                // Delete old image.
                $old_image = $this->Users->Images->get($user->image_id);
                $this->Users->Images->delete($old_image);
            }
            // Trying to create a new Images entity with $data
            $new_image = $this->Users->Images->newEntity($data['image']);
            $new_image->filename = $data['image']['name'];
            $new_image->image = $data['image’];//This part seems to be incorrect.
            $this->Users->Images->save($new_image)) {
            $user->image = $new_image;
        } else {
            $user->image_id = null;
            $user->image = null;
        }
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            this->Flash->success(__('The user profile has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit', $user->id]);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

This code doesn't save images to the database. I checked `debug($data);` and it has

```
{'image' => [
        'name' => 'image_name.png',
        'type' => 'image/png',
        'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phphmeViC',
        'error' => (int) 0,
        'size' => (int) 4003
    ]}
```

Where is the actual image file? How can I pass it to `$new_image` or `$user`?I really appreciate any helps or comments! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the model which is updating database.

Comment: A simple search on ```upload file cakephp3``` here on SO provided quite a few results to answer your question. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049805/cakephp3-upload-image-file) for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP3 - Upload image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049805/cakephp3-upload-image-file)

Comment: A MySQL DB is the wrong place to store a large amount of binary data. Just google for reasons. I wrote a plugin for abstracting storing files in CakePHP https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage check it out and read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't upload binary data like profile images in a database. Second point; just store the filename and location of the image in the DB. Sinds your website HTML loads the image from a specific path it even more easy for you. You can then do:  `<img src="{$user->profile_image}" />` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you so much! I decided not to use db to save images. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049805/cakephp3-upload-image-file this question is helpful to do so.